# Changing tick size for my IRF graphs (R studio)

Tags: r, plot, var

I am trying to change the tick size for IRF graphs for an SVAR that I estimated using the following code below:

```
SVAR1<- VAR(VARR,p=1, season=NULL, exog= NULL, type="const")
SVARmod1<- SVAR(SVAR1, Amat = amat, Bmat= NULL, hessian= TRUE, 
estmethod = c("scoring","direct"))
```

I then try to plot the IRF graphs using the following code:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
IRF_F2 <- irf(SVARmod1, impulse="deltaw2",            
response=c("Belgium","France","Germany","Italy","Netherlands"), 
n.ahead=60)
plot(IRF_F2,ylim=c(-0.5,0.3), plot.type="single", main="US Wealth 
Share Shock")
```

Non-base R Packages I use are vars and dplyr. The tick intervals from the IRF is way too small and I want to change it to intervals of 10. I have posted an image of the IRFs I get:

[image]

I was thinking of something like:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
IRF_F2 <- irf(SVARmod1, impulse="deltaw2",
          
response=c("Belgium","France","Germany","Italy","Netherlands"), 
n.ahead=60)
plot(IRF_F2,ylim=c(-0.5,0.3), plot.type="single", main="US Wealth 
Share Shock", xaxt="n")
axis(side= 1, at = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: "It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please explicitly list all non-base R packages that you are using. – MrFlick Apr 7 at 18:03" (from your last post - please follow this advice)

Comment: I have edited the question to be more helpful for possible answers. Do either of you have thoughts on this?